# on radio button change, display different buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a view where there are two radiobuttons, I want to display different buttons(of type submit) for each radiobuttons.

Below is the **rendered Html for the radiobuttons**

```
<input checked="checked" id="Isattending_0" name="Isattending" type="radio" value="Yes" />
<input id="Isattending_1" name="Isattending" type="radio" value="No" />
```

these are my **buttons**

```
<input type="submit" id="yes" class="btn btn-primary" value="Next>>" />
<input type ="submit"id="no" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
```

and this is the **script** I have written,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function defaultState() {
            $("#yes").show();
            $("#no").hide();
        })
        $('input:radio[name=Isattending]').change(function () {

            if ($("#Isattending_0").is(':checked')) {
                $("#yes").show();
                $("#no").hide();                                     
            }
            $('#Isattending_1').change(function () {

                if ($("#Isattending_0").is(':checked')) {
                    $("#no").show();
                    $("#yes").hide();                    
                }   
            })
        })

    })

</script>
```

but now, No matter which button i click, `Next>>` button is always shown or on the other hand `Submit` button is never shown, no matter which radiobutton i select.

Since by default `Isattending_0` is checked i wanted to show next button thats why i made `defaultStatefunction`. But once `Isattending_1` is checked I want to hide button `Next>>` and show button `Submit`, how do I do that?

Comment: Take your second `change` method out of the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v42xc/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(function defaultState() {
         $("#yes").show();
         $("#no").hide();
     })
     $('input:radio[name=Isattending]').change(function () {         
         if ($("#Isattending_0").is(':checked')) {
             $("#yes").show();
             $("#no").hide();  
         }else {
             $("#yes").hide();
             $("#no").show();
         }            
     })
})
```

**EDIT**

As you asked in the comment to change only the `button text`. Here is a working example [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dbK2T/)

```
Yes :<input checked="checked" id="Isattending_0" name="Isattending" type="radio" value="Yes" />
No  :<input id="Isattending_1" name="Isattending" type="radio" value="No" />

<input type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Next" />

$(document).ready(function () {
     $('input:radio[name=Isattending]').change(function () {         
         if ($("#Isattending_0").is(':checked')) {             
             $("#button").attr('value', 'Next');
         }else {            
            $("#button").attr('value', 'Submit');
         }            
     })
})
```

Comment: as mentioned in one of the answer which i voted up, would it be possible to change the text of button on radiobutton change, rather than showing different buttons? just curious...

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need 2 submits maybe you can just have one and change it's value on change.

P.S.: Sorry I can't comment...

UPDATE:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
```

UPDATE AGAIN to make sure the radio button is checked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('input:radio[name=Isattending]').change(function () {         
         if($(this).is(':checked')){
             if( $(this).val()=="Yes"){
                 $("#submit").val("Next>>");
             }
             else{
                 $("#submit").val("Submit");
             }        
         }   
     })
})
```

Comment: well from the UI point of view, if his option is yes then, he gets directed to another page where selects some dates, if not then thats it. So from the UI point of view i thought that would make sense. But you are absolutely right, If I could just change the value of the button based upon the radio button click that would be awesome. but how do i do it? +1 for your idea

Comment: I updated the reply, on the server side you can check the value of the radio that was submitted (yes or no) and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all get rid of this line:

> $('#Isattending_1').change(function ()

because a change function is already assigned to this radiobutton.
Second of all you should have 2 if-statements - one checking if the first radiobutton is checked and the second checking if the second radiobutton is checked:

```
    $('input:radio[name=Isattending]').change(function () {

        if ($("#Isattending_0").is(':checked')) {
            $("#yes").show();
            $("#no").hide();                                     
        }
        else if ($("#Isattending_1").is(':checked')) {
            $("#no").show();
            $("#yes").hide();                    
        }   
    })
```

Third of all: in case when you need simply yes/no (true/false) it is better to use a checkbox then two radiobuttons.

Comment: now by default i get both buttons, I just want `Next>>` by default to be shown as yes is checked. Another thing, when i click no, still both buttons are shown, then when i click yes button i get submit button then no matter which radio button i select always submit button is shown

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(function defaultState() {
        $("#yes").show();
        $("#no").hide();
    })
    $('input:radio[name=Isattending]').change(function () {
        if ($('input[name=Isattending]:checked').attr('id') == "Isattending_0") {
            $("#yes").show();
            $("#no").hide();                                     
        } else {
                $("#no").show();
                $("#yes").hide();                    
            }   
    })

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CJRmk/27/

Comment: your jsfiddle is not working, always shows both button

Comment: try again please. I changed link

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function defaultState() {
            $("#yes").show();
            $("#no").hide();
        })
        $('input:radio[name=Isattending]').change(function () {

            if ($("#Isattending_0").is(':checked')) {
                $("#yes").show();
                $("#no").hide();
            }
            else {
                $("#no").show();
                $("#yes").hide();
            }
        })

    })
</script>
```